# Object Representation

Tags: word, visual, open-ended

## Background

It isn't a common art style, but it is still done: using letters for form in pictures. Sometimes, people create art using *only* letters. Now, let us choose a word, i.e. Cool. 'Cool' can be used as following:

[image: Cool -> Graphic]

Cool, isn't it?

## Challenge

Your challenge is to find a word (a noun) that can be formed to describe itself pictorially. Let us presume that the word TRIANGLE could be made into a triangle. Then, this would be a valid entry.

## Rules

1. The word must have at least three letters.
2. The picture form must represent what the word is, literally.
3. You must provide a picture in your answer.
4. There can be overlap of letters, but at least have a majority of each letter showing.
5. The first letter of the word *must* be upright; the others may be rotated and shrunk, roughly maintaining its proportions.
6. All letters must be visible.

## Score

Do not tell the word, as the objective is for the best answers to float to the top. People can try and answer in comments. I will accept whichever answer/puzzle seems worthy of +15.

Comment: Loads of arbitrary rules. Especially for scoring. I recommend you delete most of the rules right now if you want people to receive this well.

Comment: The challenge is fun, the scoring not. Remember that this site is *not* about winning/loosing but about Q&A.

Comment: Is this type of question on-topic for the site? I'm concerned both about the popularity contest format and the fact that it's asking us to make word art, which I don't find that puzzley.

Comment: This doesn't really appear to be a puzzle. I'll hold off on the close-hammer for now, but this looks more like a "hey, let's have fun" and less like a legitimate puzzle or question.

Comment: @Doorknob Puzzle, noun: a game, toy, or problem designed to test ingenuity or knowledge. Is this not a problem designed to test peoples cleverness (ingenuity)?

Comment: How about most creative (broad, but a better fit)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an art contest rather than a puzzle.

Comment: @xnor The two do not necessarily have to be disjoint.

Comment: @Conor O'Brien You should also note how creativity is scored, perhaps including things such as length, overall area covered in image scaled to smallest size without losing message, etc. it will lessen how broad it is and make it more of a puzzle to find the most creative piece, rather than an art competition where the public votes on pieces.

Comment: @warspyking I think such a rule would go backwards and make it *less* interesting. In terms to make it more "puzzle"-related I would rather remove XY wins and rephrase to "Create an image-puzzle which..." and *don't* tell the word. (People can answer in the according comments) The goal then shifts to get more 'obscure' images with more letters, but they **have to** fulfill the rules nevertheless. Better answers float up by vote an the OP author may accept whatever he *likes*. Tag it open-ended and the question is (borderline) on-topic.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien so what happens if i try to answer with the word "Invisible". I think its creative but rule 6 blocks me.

Comment: Conor, I recommend you keep the current scoring I edited I as BmyGuest suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Clock

[image: Clock]

This one turned out quite well, I think.

Comment: Brilliant image, but...rule 3?

Comment: That rule was edited out. For the record, I totally saw that edit coming, and it wasn't just a case of me not reading all the rules properly :-p

Comment: You must have great foresight! :-)

Comment: @Tryth it was your (brilliant) answer that made me think how <choice word> the rule was.

Comment: Now I'm curious as to what rule 3 actually was...

Answer (score 6):

Here's my effort, a representation of the word 'toes':

[image: Picture]

Comment: Please see the note at the score changes. Thanks!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien - Thanks. I've edited accordingly. So I won't get a score of 1215.54692 after all!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture with the word **LEGO** from my website's archive.

[image: LEGO]

I made this a few years ago using [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org).